# How to show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4-x^8}}$ is differentiable on its entire domain?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I calculated the derivative of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4-x^8}}$$ and was wondering how to proof that $f(x)$ is differentiable on its entire domain: $$\left(-\sqrt[4]{(-1+\sqrt 5)/2},\sqrt[4]{(-1+\sqrt 5)/2}\right)$$

Comment: Find the derivative, then find the domain of the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, the ranges should be $1+\sqrt 5$, not $1-\sqrt 5$.

Well: $$\bigg(\frac 1g\bigg)'=\frac{-g'}{g^2}\implies f'(x)=\frac{-(\sqrt{1-x^4-x^8})'}{1-x^4-x^8}=\frac{4x^3+8x^7}{(1-x^4-x^8)^\frac 32}$$ by the chain rule. It is differentiable wherever this function is defined, which is whenever $1-x^4-x^8\neq 0$

The solutions to this equation are the end points of your interval, but since the interval is open, it doesn't contain them and hence the function is defined across that interval, so it is differentiable.

Comment: Thanks, I've just corrected the typo. My question, however, was how to proof that $f(x)$ is differentiable, not its derivative (which I've already calculated).

Comment: Yes. A function $f$ is differentiable across a domain $X$ if it's derivative $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is defined at every point  $x\in X$

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=\frac{2x^3 \left(1+2 x^4\right)}{\left(1-x^4-x^8\right)^{3/2}}$$
has the same domain as $f(x)$, thus the function is differentiable on all its domain.

---

**Edit**

Hot to find the derivative

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4-x^8}}$$
chain rule $(f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

Derivative of $u^{\alpha}$ is $\alpha u^{\alpha -1}$

Now $f(x)=(1-x^4-x^8)^{-1/2}$

then
$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\,(1-x^4-x^8)^{-1/2-1}\cdot (-4x^4-8x^7)=$$
$$=\frac{2x^4+4x^7}{(1-x^4-x^8)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Hi! I've just edited the question. My question is how to proof that $f(x)$ is differentiable, not its derivative (which I've already calculated).

Comment: @Tiamin I got it. And this is the answer: a function is differentiable if its derivative exists and is continuous on all its domain

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\frac1{g(x)}$ then $$f'(x)=-\frac{g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$$ so that $f$ is differentiable at all points $x$ such that g(x) is differentiable and $g'(x)\neq0$.  In this case, we have $g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^4-x^8},$ which is defined when $1-x^4-x^8\geq0$ and differentiable when $1-x^4-x^8>0$.  Since the domain of $g$ has been chosen so that $1-x^4-x^8>0,$ the assertion follows.